# NodeMCU/ESP8266 to drive pulse sensor?

Tags: opto-isolator, nodemcu

I have a Daikin BRP069A61, which is a heatpump accessory that allows the heatpump te smartgrid controlled. In simple terms: It will turn on when PV-power is available and will limit power to whatever is available from the grid using a pulse meter.

I want to drive the pulse meter input from this BRP069A61 using a NodeMCU. I have the NodeMCU part working in the sense that I have a PWM output which I can control. So eg when there is 1 kW of PV-output it should pulse 1000 times per hour of 0.27 times a second with a max. of 17 kW, which would mean 4,7 pulses/sec

The BRP069A61 has a 5V DC Pulse detection.

I assume I can't just connect the 3.3V PWM output of the NodeMCU to the 5V Pulse detector input of the Daikin device. So I thought I need an optocoupler. Is that correct?

If so, I need to drive an optocoupler that works with 3.3V input. I was thinking of using an PC817 which has a 1.2V forward voltage with a maximum of 6V. To 3.3V is fits in the middle.

My questions are:

- Should my idea work? Using PWM output to drive an optocoupler? and drive a pulse detection system?
- An optocoupler reverses output. Input high is output low and vice versa. How can I swap this another time around?

My schematic would be very simple.

`Input side: [NodeMCU D1] -> [R1] -> [PC817] -> GND`

`Output side: [Daikin 5V V+] -> [R2] -> [PC817] -> GND`

Would this work?

Comment: Hardware wise it looks reasonable. Software wise you don’t need pwm, just flash the output at the required rate.

Comment: Thanks. i'm using ESPHome. I think PWM is my best bet. I wouldn't know how to flash an output at the correct rate otherwise?